# Prevent object clipping in craftyJS

Tags: javascript, craftyjs

In CraftyJS, how do i stop my player entity from clipping into other entities?

This is my object:

```
        Crafty.c("Mushroom", {
        init: function() {
            this.addComponent("collision");
            this.collision(new Crafty.polygon([[8,8],[24,8],[24,24],[8,24]]));
        }
    });

    var mushroom = Crafty.e("2D, canvas, mushroomRed, Mushroom")
    .attr({x: 200, y: 150, z:1, w: 32, h: 32});
```

and this is my player onHit:

```
.onhit("mushroomRed", function() {
            this.x += this._speed;
            this.stop();
        }
```

It works only when i approach it from certain angle, otherwise, it goes haywire.

Advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using

```
this.x += this._speed;
```

to move the player away from the mushroom after they have collided. But as you are only moving it in the x direction it wont work if you collide from top or bottom. Is that your problem?

If you use the [Multiway](http://craftyjs.com/api/Multiway.html) or Fourway components you could do this instead:

```
.bind('Moved', function(from) {
    if(this.hit('mushroomRed')){
        this.attr({x: from.x, y:from.y});
    }
}).
```

Edit: complete example

```
// Init Crafty:
Crafty.init();
Crafty.canvas.init();

var player = Crafty.e("2D, Canvas, Color, player, Multiway, Collision")
   .attr({x: 0, y: 0, w: 50, h: 50})
   .color("rgb(0,255,0)")
   .multiway(3, {UP_ARROW: -90, DOWN_ARROW: 90, RIGHT_ARROW: 0, LEFT_ARROW: 180})
   .bind('Moved', function(from) {
       if(this.hit('mushroomRed')){
           this.attr({x: from.x, y:from.y});
        }
    });

var mushroom = Crafty.e("2D, Canvas, mushroomRed, Color")
    .attr({x: 200, y: 150, z:1, w: 32, h: 32})
    .color("red");
```

Running at http://jsfiddle.net/PzKVh/

This is using the latest version of Crafty 0.4.5. There has been a few breaking changes and a lot of improvements, so i would suggest you use this version.

Also, feel free to ask in the forums at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/craftyjs I think you are much more likely to find help there :-)

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate more on where do I put the code? I am quite new to Crafty and am having some difficulties. Thanks!